# Get Firestore access token for REST api with google-api-php lib

Tags: php, firebase, google-api-php-client, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to get an access token to make *REST* calls to my *Firestore* DB. I'm using PHP (only way for now) and have taken the next steps:

- Created a **service account** in the Firebase console and downloaded the key JSON
- Downloaded the Google-api-php library from https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/ and included in my code

And created this code:

```
putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS='.__DIR__ .'/key.json');
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
$client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/datastore,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform');
$client->authorize();
```

I also replaced the

```
$client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
```

part with

```
$client->setAuthConfig(__DIR__ .'/key.json');
```

Now when I var_dump the $client, the token stays NULL.

I just can't figure out, how to get the access_token for my service account. Anybody an idea how I can get an access token?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. If you want to add multiple scopes, you will have to use an array instead of a string. A string will only be treated as one single scope.
2. The `$client->authorize()` returns a `Client` instance which is authorized to to access the Google Services for the given scopes. So, `$authorizedClient = $client->authorize();` would be more appropriate.
3. If you just want to retrieve the access token, you could use `$client->fetchAccessTokenWithAssertion()`, which would give you something like this:

   ```
   Array
   (
       [access_token] => ya29.c..............
       [token_type] => Bearer
       [expires_in] => 3600
       [created] => 1511280489
   )
   ```

Here is the complete script I used to test this:

```
<?php

require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
$client->addScope([
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/datastore',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'
]);
// $client->authorize();

print_r($client->fetchAccessTokenWithAssertion());
```